# WYSIWYG editor for website with built-in syntax highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, wysiwyg

I am looking for a WYSIWYG editor for my forum website. Which has inbuilt syntax highlighting like we have in [www.stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) or [www.asp.net](http://www.asp.net/) .

So that I can save the whole text [entered by user] into the database and can render on the page with syntax highlighting.

Please help.

Don't take me wrong but I have already searched on google and Stackoverflow for this and I am not able to get the required answer.

I would appreciate if it is an open source. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like and used [tinymce](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/full.php) editor, it's sample code something like following.

```
<script src="/javascripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

tinyMCE.init({

      mode : "textareas",
      theme : "advanced",
      plugins : "safari",
      convert_urls : false,
      width : "560",
      height : "15",
      // 'code' in 'theme_advanced_buttons1' is used for the HTML content
      theme_advanced_buttons1 : "fontselect,fontsizeselect, separator, bold,italic,underline,separator,forecolor,backcolor,code, justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull",

      theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",

      theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",

      theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",

      theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left", extended_valid_elements : "a[name|href|target|title|onclick],img[class|src| border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name], hr[class|width|size|noshade],font[face|size|color|style],span[class|align|style]" });

</script>

<textarea cols="40" id="template_content" name="template[content]" rows="20"></textarea>
```